# nested grid system in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am kind of new to bootstrap and enjoying its grid system.

But there is something which is somewhat not happening. Following is the code:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" style="padding: 25px 35px 10px 35px;">Some Text Here</div>
  <div class='col-md-3' id='right-column' style='overflow: auto; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px;'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>   
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='related-post-title' style='font-size: 1.2em; text-align: center;'>Heading Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-1'>1-col</div><div class='col-xs-11'>11-col</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I was expecting that the 1-col & 11-coll text (towards the end of the code) should appear along with each other. But somehow what did not happen. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using only xs? Do you realize that iphone5/6 and larger phones aren't actually xs?

Comment: Why put padding on a col div? Don't you think that's asking for trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code more or less was alright.

It was working all right for col-xs-2 & col-xs-10, similarly for col-xs-3 and col-xs-9 and all other such similar combinations upto col-xs-6 & col-xs-6.
But wasn't working for col-xs-1 and col-xs-11.

I calculated the width of the container-row and the the col-xs-1 div and col-xs-11 div using $(selector).css('width') and .... *drumrolls*... they were 342 px, 30px and 313px respectively. (Note that this segment is inside a col-md-4 div)

Ouch... 313 + 30 > 342, hence the misfit.

So I added this in my css

```
.col-xs-11 {width: 91.21%; }
```

And it worked!!!! :-)

Thank You all for trying to help me out.

Hope this may  be helpful to someone someday.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" style="padding: 25px 35px 10px 35px;">Some Text Here</div>
  <div class='col-md-3' id='right-column' style='overflow: auto; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px;'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>   
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='related-post-title' style='font-size: 1.2em; text-align: center;'>Heading Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-1'>1-col</div><div class='col-xs-11'>11-col</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>


You were miss two div which is not closed. Please put these code. It works!
```

Comment: Not happening Chirag.

Comment: I think @user1972028 might need to read up on device resolutions.

Comment: Yes @Ringo I agree with you. 
But I figured out that the solution for this particular problem did not lie there. It was in math. Percentage & rounding off is messing it up. & it is really interesting. I will post the answer once I get the way to solve it :-)

But I appreciate your concern to improve me as a programmer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class='col-xs-1'>1-col</div><div class='col-xs-11'>11-col</div>
```

XS stands for extra small and is generally used for phones. It could be that your line breaks easily because of this. Try changing it to medium "md" instead of "xs"

- You are not closing the first row!

Comment: no luck :( I think it has something to do with the width calculations? If I change it to col-xs-10, it works. But I want to know why not for 11?

Comment: Remove padding-left and padding-right. Achieve the whitespace some other way -- ideally in a div that wraps the outermost 'container-fluid'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" style="padding: 25px 35px 10px 35px;">Some Text Here</div>
    <div class='col-md-3' id='right-column' style='overflow: auto; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px;'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>   
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='related-post-title' style='font-size: 1.2em; text-align: center;'>Heading Text</div>
    </div>
   <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-1'>1-col</div><div class='col-md-2'>11-col</div>
    </div>
   </div>  
   </div>
```

Also ensure that your screen width is ≥992px & <1200px for col-md.

The issue out here was the row containing col-1 & col-11 were inside

```
<div class='col-md-3' id='right-column' style='overflow: auto;     padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px;'>
```

i.e. max col can be 3, beyond this will render on the next line.

Good luck & hope this helps.

Comment: No @dev. the code inside col-md-3 can again be divided into 12. so inside that col-md-1 and col-md-11 are legitimate combination. Which unfortunately for some reason is not working. It works for col-md-1 and col-md-10 (or any number less than 11, 2 in ur example) but not for 11